# Where can I post my story, but keep the formatting?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, websites, electronic-publishing

My friend and I are working on a story that we want to publish and share on the internet (kind of like what FictionPress does), but we have some formatting worked into our story that we would like to keep intact.

The two major pieces of formatting that we would like to keep is **text color** and **Zalgo text** (ex. Y͡O̸̧͘U͡ ̢D̶͝I̡͢D T͡HI̷̸S̶͡͝ ̡͏TO͘ ͜Ḿ̴E) (not because our story has anything to do with Zalgo, but because it makes our "glitched out" character's dialog a bit more fitting).

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend you to create a blog and post your story there - you can share the account with your friend so you don't have to work alone -, because you'll lose little to nothing at all about formatting and you can include photos, which is something that you probably can't do at Fanfiction.com.

Nota that I do not reccomend you to post at a website that you intend to use like an online portfolio, because editors tend to shy away from writers who write fanfiction (which I assume is what you are writing) that use other people's work, like characters, stting, etecetera. Basically, fanfiction that are not original fanfictions.

Plus, with some work from your side you customise the entire site to your liking, which I find really pleasent. Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super sure but I advise you to check out "wattpad".

Comment: Can you expand your answer please?